# Autowired fields are null, but not when autowiring by constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a component which autowires some other beans:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env; // null

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(ConfigurationUtils configUtils /* not null */) {
    }
}
```

When adding the `Environment env` as a constructor parameter it isn't null as well.

But why?

**UPDATE**

```
@Component
public class MyComponent implements InitializingBean {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private Environment env; // TODO: null

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(ConfigurationUtils configUtils) {
        log.debug("configUtils == null: " + (configUtils == null));
        log.debug("env == null: " + (env == null));
        log.debug(env.getProperty("foo")); // to trigger NPE
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        log.debug("Initialized environment: " + env);
    }
}
```

console output:

```
DEBUG c.e.MyComponent - configUtils == null: false
DEBUG c.e.MyComponent - env == null: true
WARN  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/site/WEB-INF/lib/site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/example/MyComponent.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.example.MyComponent]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:649) [servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.example.MyComponent]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.MyComponent.<init>(MyComponent.java:23) ~[site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/site/WEB-INF/lib/site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/example/MyComponent.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.example.MyComponent]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:649) [servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.example.MyComponent]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.MyComponent.<init>(MyComponent.java:23) ~[site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where do you check `env` for `null`? It's possible that you're checking the field before the bean has been fully constructed.

Comment: In the constructor of `MyComponent` (see updated question)

Comment: This is expected behavior since when calling the constructor no other autowiring has been applied yet. See bean lifecycle by ursa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface into your bean and check property in it:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env; // null

    @Autowired
    public MyComponent(ConfigurationUtils configUtils /* not null */) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Initialized environment: " + env);
    }
}
```

Default Spring bean life-cycle:

- create object / call constructor with (autowired?) arguments
- fill (autowired?) bean properties (fields & setters)
- call afterPropertiesSet (if bean implements InitializingBean)
- publish reference on bean
- ...
- drop reference on bean
- call destroy (if bean implements DisposableBean)

Comment: there's no console output saying "Initialized environment: ..." (see updated question)

Comment: But adding it as a constructor parameter works instead of autowiring by field.

Comment: I've added bean life-cycle description